# Setting and starting autofilter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet and it links to another workbook. The issue is when the filter is on it does not change as new data is added; you have to refilter the data.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I know there is a way to have it autofilter as data appears using a Macro. I have been trying to figure the Macro out for 5 hours now and can not get it right. The closest I've gotten is I set a filter and then when new data appears, it erases the filter and adds all data together.  I need the filter to stay!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Me.FilterMode = True Then
        With Application
           .EnableEvents = False
           .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        With ActiveWorkbook
            .CustomViews.Add ViewName:="B2", RowColSettings:=True
          Me.AutoFilterMode = False
            .CustomViews("B2").Show
            .CustomViews("B2").Delete
        End With


         With Application
           .EnableEvents = True
           .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: please post the code you have built so far and then we can help you edit it to get it working...

Comment: Crap I apologize its not putting it in neatly how it is actually... Data is coming in how I want I just can not get it to sort by "Focus Factory" like I want... All the data just compiles there from west east and north even with a filter on specifying the north

Comment: edit your post and put the code there, not in a comment.

Comment: just entered image of spread sheet to

Comment: I appreciate you guys and any help you can provide I would like to start my holiday but need to figure this out first!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially all you need to is "refresh" the filter by telling Excel to filter the same conditions on the new range of data.

Note that the use of `UsedRange` implies that all data is in contiguous rows and columns. Also, adjust the `AutoFilter` arguments as needed.

Since your data is linked via formulas, the `Worksheet_Change` will never fire when formulas are updated. You'll need to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event, but be mindful this will fire **everytime** the worksheet calculates, which may or may not be burdensome.

I also changed your conditional `If` to say `IF Me.AutoFilterMode = True` since the `FilterMode` will not be true if nothing is actually filtered, even if the filters are on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Me.AutoFilterMode = True Then

        With Application
           .EnableEvents = False
           .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        Me.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, "North" 'filters column B for myFilter value change as needed

         With Application
           .EnableEvents = True
           .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just added the code to my sheet and changed the "myFilter" to "North" because I want to filter it for that... Though as it pulls data from my other workbook its not filtering unless I go click the filter button still...

Comment: Sorry if it feels like your having to spoon feed me..

Comment: how does it "pull data from my other workbook"? by code?

Comment: Its attached to another workbook and copies whatever was put in that workbook so =IF('[Daily Data Entry.xlsm]1st'!$I$8="","",'[Daily Data Entry.xlsm]1st'!$I$8) for example... So whenever data is entered there it pops up in this one and when that happens I need it to be filtered out by north in column b

Comment: ah, okay. that is why it's not working, because the `Worksheet_Change` event does not fire when formulas are updated You have to use `Worksheet_Calculate` - which can be tricky, because the code will fire everytime the worksheet is calculated. Editing my post now @Mitch.

Comment: Still didn't budge... :( I just should have to change "myFilter" to "North" and it should sort it every time a calculation occurs right?

Comment: Well, there is the condition if `AutoFilterMode = True`. If the filter is not currently set it will not, because `AutoFilterMode` will be False, so make sure the Filter is turned on. Nothing has to actually be filterd, but make sure you can see the Filter Arrows.

Comment: IDK GOD I even enabled to trust macros to ensure it and nothing happened and nothing is happening as data pops in and yes filiter is on I can see the triangles... :(

Comment: did you step through the code by putting a breakpoint in the code and seeing what happens?

Comment: I know enough to roughly get by in VBA but I am unsure of how to do what your saying